# Following users like twitter in Django, Admin UI

Tags: python, django, model

This is the class that i have created to make a user follow model. But, it doesn't seem to work right. When I create a following in the admin, it keeps opening a new add UserFollwing window to fill the 'follow' field. So, I am unable to create it.

```
class UserFollowing(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followed_by', symmetrical=False)
```

Also, if I create it in the shell using:

```
tim, c = User.objects.get_or_create(username='tim')
chris, c = User.objects.get_or_create(username='chris')
tim.userfollowing.follows.add(chris.userfollowing)
```

the shell exits giving error:

```
fest.models.DoesNotExist: User has no userfollowing.
```

Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a UserFollowing object that associates with the user before setting follows attribute?

I.E.:

Assuming you have the models:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, primary_key=True)
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s the restaurant" % self.place.name
```

You would type into the shell:

```
>>> p1 = Place(name='Demon Dogs', address='944 W. Fullerton')
>>> p1.save()
>>> r = Restaurant(place=p1, serves_hot_dogs=True, serves_pizza=False)
>>> r.save()

>>> # accessing the restaurant as a property of the place
>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Demon Dogs the restaurant>
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/ for more details

Comment: >>> p = User.objects.get(id=2)
>>> m = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> pa = UserFollowing(user=p, follows = m) //gives error                            >>> pa = UserFollowing(user=p, followed_by = m) //gives error

Comment: TypeError: 'follows' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: It's because follows is a ManyToMany field so I don't think you can set it in the constructor. Instead, after creating the object (passing only the user=p argument), you then write something like pa.follows.add(m)

Comment: yes i did that too and it worked. One more thing, i am able to display the user field in the UserProfile admin, but the follows field can't be added as it gives "'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'username'" error. Is it possible to show it in the admin?

Comment: I think this is different from your original question and that you should ask that as a separate question and post information about how you are trying to show the field (i.e., admin.py). I'm not sure if we should continue this back & forth via comments.